# If I pass an address of a variable do I have to do a return?

Tags: c, pointers, global-variables, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

If I have a function that increments a *global* variable according to some rule and I pass a variable by reference, do I have to do a return or will the variable be updated anyway? Would this also work with a local variable? For example:

```
static uint8_t counter = 1;

void add(uint8_t *variable)
{
   if (*variable == 5)
   {
    *variable = 7;

   } else if (*variable == 20)
   {
    *variable = 1;
   } else
   {
    *variable++;
   }
}
```

And I call the 'add' function somewhere like:

```
void function(void)
{
... some code...
add(&counter);
... some code...
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing it incorrectly in general and there is a better way to go about this...

Comment: If you have a global (but `static`) variable, and the `add` function is in the same translation unit, why pass an argument in the first place?

Comment: It appears that you're actually passing the value of the pointer(not by ref), though this code makes little sense in general. If the variable is global you shouldn't need to pass it. Also, there's a possibility that two of the dereferences in add are unnecessary.

Comment: If the purpose of the function is to calculate a value, based on the argument(s), why not return the value as a *return* value? This avoids passing a pointer to the function, and modifying the object they point to inside the function. For example: how would you like `void sin(double *result, double rads):`

Comment: Also note that C doesn't have *references*, but you can *emulate* it by using pointers.

Comment: Everyone else has provided good guidance and you should listen to it, but to answer your question: no, you don't need a return statement when you update the variable via a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work with any kind of variable whether it is global or local because the object is passed by reference.

However the better interface is when the function returns the pointer that it gets as the argument.

```
uint8_t * add(uint8_t *variable)
{
   if (*variable == 5)
   {
    *variable = 7;

   } else if (*variable == 20)
   {
    *variable = 1;
   } else
   {
    *variable++;
   }

  return variable;
}
```

In this case you can combine calls of the function or use it with other functions that await the same pointer. For example

```
add( add( &counter ) );
```

or

```
SomeOtherFunction( add( &counter ) );
```

A difference exists when the function is called in multi threaded environment and the global variable has no the storage class specifier _Thread_local.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid global variables.

If you do have to use a global variable, you don't need to pass it at all - you can directly modify it i.e. you neither need to pass nor return it.

```
static uint8_t counter = 1;

void add(void)
{
   if (counter == 5) {
    counter = 7;
   } else if (counter == 20) {
    counter = 1;
   } else {
    counter++;
   }
}
```

If you are using an existing interface `add()` that needs to work for both global variables and some local variables passed from a function.
Then your existing function is fine as is and you don't need to return anything as you are the address of the variable you want to modify and update its content.

Comment: Yes, although I am using a global variable I wanted to be able to use it with local variables as well. I know I could just simply pass the value of a variable and return an incremented value, but using a pointer seemed to be more efficient.

Comment: I did think it's one of the possibilities. That's why I added the last paragraph. In that case, your function is good and will work for both local and global variables. In fact, the lifetime of the object is irrelevant as far as the function `add()` is concerned - it'll just update whatever you pass it. But be aware of *data race* if you happen to have multiple threads and possibly pass the address of `counter` to various functions (or use the value of `counter` in multiple threads).

Answer (score 0):

For a global (*file scope*) variable,  you don't need to pass it explicitly to the function, at all. It is already in global scope and accessible from all the function (block scopes), **provided** you don't have another local identifier of the same name in the local (inner) scope.

That said, for a *to the point* answer, no, you don't need to return the updated value, it is already reflected in the *actual argument* (`counter`) passed to the function. This is same for both global scope and non-global scope variables.

Answer (score 0):

Global variable has visibility across your file, so it is known to the function to which you are passing its address.

Why do you need a pointer when global variable is visible within the function?

You can just change the value of it and the changed value is visible in calling function.

If your question was for a non-global variable then

```
    void func(int *q);   

    int main()
    {
       int a;
       func(&a);
       printf("%d \n",a);
    }

    void func(int *q)
    {
       *q = 10;
    }
```

No need to return anything from the function because you are passing the address of the variable and changes done to the location are visible in the calling function